# Read Android Local Database Data ,make it as JSON Format ,Send to webServer Using RestAPI

Tags: android, json, android-json

1.I am taking data from Local Database every 10 mins sending to web server.

2.after reading from Local database , make Full database data as **Json format** then **send to Webserver from android**.

**I want to make Like this:**

```
[
  {
    "$id": "2",
    "Contact": "999",
    "Lat": "465465",
    "Long": "65465",
    "Time": "654654",
    "Msg": "1"
  },
  {
    "$id": "3",
    "Contact": "12131321",
    "Lat": "3413132",
    "Long": "54564",
    "Time": "54654",
    "Msg": "1"
  }
]
```

**Reading from Local Database:**

```
List<LocationPOJO> val = dbconnectorForlocation.getAllvalues();

Log.i("MY data String ",val.toString());
for(int i=0;i<val.size();i++)
{
    ImeiStringval = val.get(i).getIMEIString();
    LatstringVal = val.get(i).getLatString();
    LongStringVal = val.get(i).getLongString();
    StatusStingVal = val.get(i).getStatusString();
    TimeandDateVal=val.get(i).getTImeandDate();
}
```

Please,help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
JSONObject json;
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<dbData.size;i++)
{
json= new JSONObject();
json.put("$id", dbData.get(i).getId());
json.put("Contact", dbData.get(i).getContact());
json.put("Lat", dbData.get(i).getLat());
json.put("Long", dbData.get(i).getLong());
json.put("Time", dbData.get(i).getTime());
json.put("Msg", dbData.get(i).getMsg());
jsonArray.put(json);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,i want to read 100,s of data. i don,t want to create 100 json object.

Comment: use for loop with your db data